# Nested for loops in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, for-loop, vector, nested-loops

I've dabbled in a few programming languages and loops have been a weak spot for me, and MATLAB has been no different.  The scenario I'm working with has two variable sets, call them x and y where length(x) = 3 and length(y) = 6.  For the function that uses x and y as inputs, I'm trying to run x(1) for each instance of y, then x(2) and x(3).  The results would ideally be stored in a 6x3 matrix but for now trying a 1x18.  My results are coming out very strange so I think I'm doing something incorrect.  Is this the right approach for this type of nested loop?

```
for i = 1:length(x)
for i2 = 1:length(y)
result(i2*i) = func(x(i),y(i2));
end
end
```

I've tried a few variations of this nested loop with mixed results.  Most frequently the results vector has data in the first 6 positions and the rest are zeros.

Comment: Do `result(i2,i)` to make a 2D matrix. Writing into a 1D matrix is much more complex. Multiplying the two indices together will certainly not get you there. Note how 2\*1 and 1\*2 are the same, so there are two combinations written into the same array element with your indexing.

Comment: Yeah I realized afterwards that the multiplier was overwritting some previous entries.  I haven't practiced storing into matrices much, so that is very helpful and makes a lot more sense for what I was trying to accomplish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
result=zeros(length(x),length(y)); %preallocate for speed
for xidx=1:length(x)
    for yidx=1:length(y)
        result(xidx,yidx)=func(x(xidx),y(yidx));
    end
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.